# How To Parse JSON in R Without "Losing" Empty Elements

Tags: json, r

I am trying to parse JSON that is coming to me in the form of an array of arrays (think a table of data). The issue is that this table may contain arrays or maps as elements and these elements may by empty. Here is an example:

```
json <- '[[1,"foo",[],{}],[1,"bar",[1],{"foo":"bar"}]]'

# Result is a list of 2 where each sublist is of length 4
jsonlite::fromJSON(json)

# Result is a character vector of length 6
> unname(unlist(jsonlite::fromJSON(json)))
[1] "1"   "foo" "1"   "bar" "1"   "bar"
```

So when I try and cast this to a 2 by 4 matrix I am getting the wrong answer. I would like `[]` to map to the string `"[]"` and `{}` to `"{}"` so I don't lose elements. It is totally fine for me to return the nested array as `"[1]"` instead of parsing it as a list. To me this seems like I need to tell the json parser to stop recursing and treat the elements as characters at a certain point but I can't figure out how to do this. I'm not tied to the jsonlite package so basically anything is fair game as long as it is not slow.

Comment: I didn't think having a nested named list would work into a matrix (`{"foo":"bar"}`). Frankly, unless all of your `object`s will be single elements (and you remove either the key or value), it does not make sense to try to map it to a matrix. You may need to consider pruning the whole structure before trying to create a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could recursively iterate the parsed json to find the empty lists and replace them with the values you want. For example

```
renameEmptyLists <- function(x) {
    if (is.list(x)) {
        if( length(x)==0 ) {
        return(if(!is.null(names(x))) { "{}" } else {"[]"} )
        } else {
            return(lapply(x, renameEmptyLists))
        }
    } else {
        x
    }
}

jj <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json)
unname(unlist(renameEmptyLists(jj)))
# [1] "1"   "foo" "[]"  "{}"  "1"   "bar" "1"   "bar"
```

And to be clear, you where "loosing" them during the `unlist()`. If you look at the `jj` object in my example, you will see that the parse correctly identified the empty list and the empty named list.